# Pandas isin() gives ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check whether the date I am working with is already existing in a DataFrame. If yes, I would like to add values from another DataFrame to the count column for this date's row. I no, I would like just to concat new row to the DataFrame.

My Data Frames look like this:

result_df:

```
       date     count
0 '2021-01-01'    10           
1 '2021-01-02'    13       
...
```

temp_df:

```
      date      count          
0 '2021-01-02'    8
```

The code I am using is following:

```
date = '2021-01-02'
if result_df.loc[result_df['date'].isin([date])].any():
   result_df.loc[result_df['date'] == date, 'count'] += temp_df['count']
else:
   result_df = pd.concat([result_df, temp_df], ignore_index=True)
```

As a result I have following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: The error *does not* come from `.isin`. It comes from `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific to what you're trying, you can get the matching dates using this:

```py
result_df['date'].isin(temp_df['date'])
0    False
1     True
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

But since you want add `count` from the two df's when `date` matches, use [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to create a dataframe with the necessary matches, and then add the count from the df on the 'right':

```py
merged = result_df.merge(temp_df, how='left', on='date', suffixes=('', '_y')).fillna(0)
result_df['count'] += merged['count_y']
```

Note that this will match on each `date` which is common in both df's, not just one date value. So you can do this for all matching dates `temp_df` in one go.

`fillna` is used to put in a 0 for the `count`s which are missing in `temp_df`. In the `merged` dataframe, it has `_y` suffix:

```
           date  count  count_y
0  '2021-01-01'     10      0.0
1  '2021-01-02'     13      8.0
```

Final `result_df` is:

```
           date  count
0  '2021-01-01'   10.0
1  '2021-01-02'   21.0
```

---

For the error you're getting, see this question - [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36921951/1431750).

Comment: Thank you a lot for giving me a fresh view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are matching for one date only, like the sample data, you can try:

```
date = '2021-01-02'
result_df.loc[result_df['date'].isin([date]), 'count'] += temp_df.loc[temp_df['date'] == date, 'count'].values
```

**Result:**

```
print(result_df)

         date  count
0  2021-01-01     10
1  2021-01-02     21
```

The reason your codes get the error is because Python if-statement cannot handle a Pandas Series which contains multiple values.  As your code with `.isin()` actually return a boolean Series with 2 `True`/`False` values corresponding to the checking results of the 2 rows of the 2 dates.  Hence, the error.  You have to replace your use of Python if-statement to only Pandas / numpy codes to properly handle it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if the date is in the column if I understand you correctly. That can be done like this:

```
date = '2021-01-02'
if date in result_df['date'].values:
   result_df.loc[result_df['date'] == date, 'count'] += temp_df['count']
else:
   result_df = pd.concat([result_df, temp_df], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a big help, I will definitely try it.